# Fail2ban - Add manually ip from php script using exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, security, fail2ban

i'm trying to add ip to fail2ban banlist instantly when detect differs types of ungrateful visitors, i'm trying do this from php script running next command with 'shell' or 'shell_exec':

> exec('fail2ban-client -vvv set ssh-iptables banip 123.123.123.123');

(I would like use native detections of fail2ban and additionally add or remove bans manually from my admin zone in my own website.)

But, this method doesn't work...

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try with full path of fail2ban-client you can get it by entering

```
which fail2ban-client
```

at shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this command outputs: > /usr/bin/fail2ban-client

Comment: then change your code to exec('/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -vvv set ssh-iptables banip 123.123.123.123');

Comment: from php script this command no output any response and doesn't work, the ip is not blocked, but from ssh logged as root: [root@ns1 bin]# /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -vvv set ssh-iptables banip 123.123.123.123
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
INFO   Using socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
DEBUG  OK : '123.123.123.123'
DEBUG  Beautify '123.123.123.123' with ['set', 'ssh-iptables', 'banip', '123.123.123.123']
123.123.123.123
[root@ns1 bin]#

Comment: my theory, fail2ban-client binnary is launching correctly, but from php script doesn't acces to main configuration... for example, shell('fail2ban-client --help'); shows correctly help documentation...

Comment: maybe you should give config file to fail2ban-client with "-c" option check documentation... http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Client

Comment: yeah, it seems so... it is working but can't file config file so can't access it. config files generally under /etc check fail2ban config file in this directory.

Comment: exactly, it can't access to files located in this directory from php script, so it this instance of fail2ban-client can't work correctly... any idea to get my objetive?
Thanks

Comment: if you know path of config you can give it via -c option so make your command like this exec('/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -c _PATH_OF_CONFIG_FILE -vvv set ssh-iptables banip 123.123.123.123'); if your php file can't access it, just copy it a readable place. we can't know where is it located without knowing your linux distro and version. You have to find it, look in /etc

Comment: I would be interested in this topic, but the discussion seems over and has left me with many questions. Is this discussion closed? Did it work in the end? Were you able to access or copy the configuration file? What is this configuration file? Can a symlink be used? I'm on ubuntu 20.04